# how is this page dynamically loading the correct images?

Tags: javascript, ajax

While familiarizing myself with AJAX, I came across the following issue I do not understand.

Usually, when an online shop loads a new page of product results dynamically, the page requests a resource that specifies which product data it wants (eg products 100-200), and then positions the received data (brand, price, etc.) on the page.

Poking around this [this site](http://www.marni.com/marni/search/New_Arrivals/WOMEN/season/secondary/tskay/3FD17CD7/gender/D/collection_id/16073) with firebug, I noticed that when a new page of products gets loaded dynamically, no such resource gets requested. It appears that all data (except images) for all products is static, and only the image URLs get requested when switching between pages.

I am puzzled how the page knows which images to request, given that the names of the big images are not on the static page. I noticed that the names of the thumbnail images at the bottom of the page are identical to the names of the big images with the exception of an extension (8P_F versus 13P_F).

I am guessing the developer might be simply modifying the thumbnail image names to make the requests for the big images, but my knowledge of Javascript is sufficiently poor that I cannot identify where this happens. Is that what is going on here?

Comment: Given the prices they ask for those close, they can probably afford magic unicorns to do all the work.

Comment: @Pointy A valid point. Sadly I myself must resort to learning AJAX.

Comment: Look at itemlib.js. It isn't magic.

Comment: Anyway I think your guess is correct - there's a bunch of JavaScript on the page (Prototype/Scriptaculous code) and it somehow keeps track of product groups and computes the image URLs according to some common scheme.

Comment: @nobody where do you see "itemlib.js" referenced?  I see some scripts but none with that name. Maybe it depends on the browser ...

Comment: I used chrome and i just watched the timeline and looked at the javascript that was evaluated just before all of the requests for the images. And it does change the image urls the way that you described.

Comment: commonlib.js loads itemlib.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the page is using AJAX to get these images at all. If you use Fiddler you can see that when the arrow is clicked a request is made for the images directly. No packaged image data (urls for example) are actually returned. The small icons contain the base image name data. I suspect that they are just stripping this from the string, postpending a different string and setting the source attributes.

I imagine they do something simple like.

```
var smallImgURL = document.getElementById('smallimageX');
var bigImgUrl = smallImgUrl.substring(0, smallImageUrl.indexOf('_'));
var bigImgUrl += '13P_F';
//call a fancy placeholder animation
document.getElementById('bigimageContainer').src = bigImgUrl;
//when load completes show image
```